# Copy excel row vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel spreadsheet with many worksheet.

i want to copy the first row from "Sheet1" into all other sheets at row 1 AND maintain the column widths specified from row1 sheet one.

any ideas how this can be done?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help you!

The following code pastes the first row of the sheet named "Sheet1" in each of the other sheets' first row. In case the source sheet's name is different, change the HeaderRow's sheet reference appropriately.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, HeaderRow As Range
Set HeaderRow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("1:1")
HeaderRow.Copy

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range(HeaderRow.Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        ws.Paste
Next ws
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Please hit the green tick beside the answer, if you feel this is your solution...

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlColumnWidths`?

To elaborate:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BL50000").Copy

With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths

End With
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1: "xlPasteColumnWidths"?  Wow, I really do learn something new everyday here.